# Unable to make shadow below a canvas that shows vega charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to make my chart float on the screen. For that I am trying to get the canvas that holds my rendered chart to have a shadow. But no matter what I search about getting shadows for a canvas element, it doesn't work.

The code that I have so far for the shadow is -

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("marks")[0];
if (canvas.getContext)
    {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
      ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 20;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 20;
    //  ctx.fill();
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

The whole HTML looks like this -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-projection-extended@2"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vis"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var spec = {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
      "config": {
        "view": {
          "continuousHeight": 300,
          "continuousWidth": 400
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/cars.json"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "Origin",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Horsepower",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Miles_per_Gallon",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": "point"
    };
    var opt = {"renderer": "canvas", "actions": false};
    vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, opt);
  </script>

<span class="update_time">Updated at 2020-02-24 12:10</span>

</body>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("marks")[0];
if (canvas.getContext)
    {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
      ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
      ctx.shadowOffsetX = 20;
      ctx.shadowOffsetY = 20;
    //  ctx.fill();
    }
}, false);
</script>
</html>
```

How should I modify my script to have a shadow appear below my chart on one side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `canvas` is an HTML element, you would use CSS and the [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property to alter its presentation.

Also, it is invalid to have any content after the closing `body` tag and before the closing `html` tag. So, if you were going to need that last `script` element (which you don't now), it should be just prior to the closing `body` tag.

Lastly, the following line:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("marks")[0];
```

is really [not a good approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) to getting your DOM element reference and should really be (in future cases where you'll need it, but it won't be necessary at all here):

```
var canvas = document.querySelector(".marks");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-projection-extended@2"></script>

  <style>
    canvas { border:1px solid black; box-shadow: 4px 4px 1px grey; }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    var spec = {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
      "config": {
        "view": {
          "continuousHeight": 300,
          "continuousWidth": 400
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/cars.json"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "Origin",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Horsepower",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "Miles_per_Gallon",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      },
      "mark": "point"
    };
    var opt = {"renderer": "canvas", "actions": false};
    vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, opt);
  </script>

  <div class="update_time">Updated at 2020-02-24 12:10</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just realized one thing....the script I added for the shadow actually doesn't do anything at all. The shadow follows the specifications in the css only. Any idea how do I fix that? Do i even need js for shadow below canvas? From css is it possible to handle the offset of the shadows?

Comment: @jar As you can see, I've removed that `script` as it doesn't do anything and isn't needed. It's all done with CSS.